# Determining whether an improper integral converges or diverges.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x^7+2}}{x^4}\text{dx}$$

I was told to let $f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^4}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^7+2}}{x^4}$ then find the limit as $x$ approaches $\infty$ of $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\text{dx}$.

I found that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} =0$. According to the limit comparison test, $0<L<\infty$, since the limit is $0$, this integral will diverge. Is this correct?

Also how do you determine $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to use the limit comparison test?

Comment: I don't know why somebody would suggest $\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^4}$. The informative comparison would be with $h(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^7}}{x^4} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. You get $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{h(x)}{g(x)} = 1$, and hence the integral of $g$ diverges since the integral of $h$ does.

Comment: If the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ is $1$, doesn't it converge?

Comment: Since $$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = \infty,$$ the same asymptotic behaviour means that the integral of $g$ also diverges.

Comment: So the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ does not determine whether or not the integral diverges or converges?

Comment: Here is one of the examples related to this problem. http://i.imgur.com/LLXsjxM.png I was wondering about their choice of $f(x)$ as well.

Comment: Not alone. With information about the convergence or divergence of the integral of $f$ it can tell you whether the integral of $g$ converges. (I assume $f > 0$, and that $g$ has no singularities, so the behaviour for $x \to\infty$ is the only interesting point) If $\int f < \infty$ and $\liminf \frac{f}{\lvert g\rvert} > 0$, then the integral of $g$ converges. And if the integral of $f$ diverges, and $\limsup \frac{f}{g} < \infty$, then the integral of $g$ diverges too.

Comment: In that example, a function with the same asymptotic behaviour is used, then (since the limit of the quotient exists, is finite and nonzero), either both integrals converge, or both integrals diverge. You need to look at one of the two functions closer to find out which.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{x \gg 1\,,\quad\mbox{integrand}\ \sim x^{-1/2}\,,\quad\mbox{integral}\ \sim x^{1/2}:\
\mbox{Diverges !!!.}}$

Answer (score 0):

By the test you have mentioned, the integral will diverge.

Think about it for a second and it will make sense. With that limit you showed that $f$ "grows slower" than g. Finding out that the integral of $f$ diverges means that $f$ grows "too fast" to converge.

Then, also g grows too fast and the integral will diverge. That's the meaning of the limit comparison test.

Well, $g$ will probably always be the function of interest to integrate and $f$ will usually be a simpler function to integrate and that grows faster or slower than $g$.

Looking at $g$, you can see that as $x \to \infty$, the function behaves like $x^{-1/2}$. So your intuition should tell that $\int g$ diverges, and you must choose $f$ such that $\int f$ also diverges (easily provable) and grows slower than $g$, so you can use limit comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

What you were told doesn't make sense.  What I would do if I were you is to find a simpler function that is bounded by the numerator, say $f(x)=x^{3.5}$, as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and another that bounds it, say $f(x)=x^{3.5}+2$.  Now, with $g(x) = x^4$ you ought to be able to perform the resulting integral for both of these $f(x)$ and show that it either converges or diverges.